# Getting logged out of application while trying to share session among multiple applications

Tags: laravel, session, single-sign-on

I have two Laravel applications connected to the same database; what I'm trying to implement is to allow the user to log in to one application and will enable the user to stay logged in to another application.

The first application is hosted on suppose app1.example.com, and the Laravel version for it is (5.6.*), the second is hosted on suppose app2.example.com, and the Laravel version for it is (^9.19).

The APP_KEY for both is the same; some information from the env file is as follows for both applications.

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com
SESSION_COOKIE=example
SESSION_CONNECTION=mysql
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

I have created a sessions table; the migration details are as follows.

```
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->primary();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->index();
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity')->index();
});
```

The contents of the sessions file is as follows for both applications

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other excellent drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file," "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 1440),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
    | cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
    | correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
    |
    */

    'store' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict"
    |
    */

    'same_site' => null,

];
```

The issue I face while logging in to some applications is that whenever I log in to any application and navigate to the 2nd one, I have to log in again rather than staying logged in to it. Also, after I navigate back to the first application, I get logged out of that. Please guide me on what I might be doing wrong in this case.

Comment: u want to share the session or not? if u share the session, means if u login in app A, u'll be logged in in app B too. And same for logout. I dont understand your issue

Comment: I want to share the session, but the sessions are not being shared, if I login to the 1st application, and open the 2nd application, I get logged out of the first one as well. I don't login to the second application

Comment: @ericmp I have also edited my question, please check it out if it helps. Thanks

Comment: i followed this tutorial and i made it to work. just read carefully and follow the steps. u'll get it - https://medium.com/@zsolt.gyure96/how-to-share-sessions-between-two-laravel-applications-4b9d061fa599

Comment: I have also followed the same tutorial, I can't get it to work, can you guide me what I might be doing wrong, if anymore information is needed, let me know